# Is this Bubble Sort or Quick Sort?

Tags: c, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

int main() {
  int data[10], no, i, j, n, c;

  printf("\n Enter no of elements :");
  scanf("%d", &no);
  printf("\nEnter the data");
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &data[i]);
  }
  n = MAX;
  do {
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) {
        data[i] = data[i] + data[i + 1];
        data[i + 1] = data[i] - data[i + 1];
        data[i] = data[i] - data[i + 1];
      }
    }
    n = n - 1;
    for (i = MAX - 1, c = 0; i >= c; i--) {
      if (data[i] < data[i - 1]) {
        data[i] = data[i] + data[i - 1];
        data[i - 1] = data[i] - data[i - 1];
        data[i] = data[i] - data[i - 1];
      }
    }
    c = c + 1;
  } while (n != 0 && c != 0);
  printf("The sorted array is:");
  for (i = 0; i < no; i++) {
    printf("%d\t", data[i]);
  }
}
```

I was confident it was bubble sort at first glance, until I saw the second looping – which confused me. Why would it sort from behind as well?

Could anyone tell me if it's a Bubble Sort or another type of sort?

Comment: I think it's a variation on shuttle sorting.  It is not Quicksort — that much is sure.  There's no partitioning step, and no actual recursion or recursion-in-disguise. (simulated with a stack).  See Wikipedia on [Cocktail Shaker Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort) which gives numerous alternative names including Shuttle Sort.

Comment: One thing is for certain: The names of the variables and the lack of comments make it 10 times more difficult to determine what the algorithm is.

Comment: Cocktail shaker sort, a.k.a. bi-directional bubble sort.

Comment: @paddy it's a question that my lecturer give to my class and I had to agree the variables make it so hard to know which algorithm it is. Sorry for that!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler first time hearing it, thanks for the help :D

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess it's designed to simulate real-world scenarios where it's quite common to come across semi-obfuscated code written by someone who wasn't thinking about readability / maintainability.

Comment: @robthebloke ah I see now, makes sense after you mentioned the bi-directional bubble sort. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @paddy hahaha could be the reason xD. Anyway thanks!